# How do I use firebase v3 in Ionic2 via npm?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I have this error in firebase/auth.js and firebase/database.js:

> rollup: Use of eval is strongly discouraged, as it posses security risks

This must be error in firebase node_module! I can't understand what's going on.

It's working When I remove **firebase.initializeApp(config)**

But, having same error on adding above.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No error, only a warning. Seems to be in a node package, so there isn't really much you can do about it

Comment: Just make sure you keep your firebase node_module up to date, they'll probably fix this issue (or already have) in later versions

Comment: But that causes an error in browser console - and Project can't be run.

auth.js:21 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Updated question for browser console error.

Comment: Anyone have solution?? I couldn't run ionic serve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Firebase v3 in Ionic2 Via NPM is not working at all!! Had lot's of problems in their node module.

So, I found a solution.. follow the link below, where discussion has been made for similar problem.
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/is-it-possible-to-use-firebase-v3-in-ionic-2/54387

And here is the direct link of solution ..
https://github.com/aaronksaunders/ionic2firebase3

**Simply, do not use Firebase v3 in Ionic2 Via NPM, unless they fix problems in their firebase node module.**