# Set up "firebase javascript" to use with "ionic serve"

Tags: node.js, cordova, firebase, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to use [Firebase Javascript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup), in an Ionic 2 project so I can **develop** the **Push Notification logic that I want to apply**, and **test it in a browser**, by using the **CLI "ionic serve"**.

I've followed the step as explain in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) under node.js / ES2015:

I did a CLI "npm install --save firebase" to add it to my project.

And then at the top of one of my project service I did:

```
import [regular Ionic 2 and Angular 2 import stuffs];

import * as firebase from 'firebase';
@Injectable()
export class PushNotifService {

  constructor(private platform:Platform){
    console.log("PushNotifService starts");
    console.info(this.platform);
   console.info(firebase);
  }


}
```

I ran into the problem described in that [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41257526/rollup-use-of-eval-is-strongly-discouraged-as-it-posses-security-risks).

I've tried then a different approach, by importing the file "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase.js", then I added it to [my project]/src/assets/js/firebase.js.

In [my project]/src/index.html i added:

```
<body> 
  <ion-app></ion-app> 
  <script src="assets/js/firebase.js"></script>
</body>
```

And in my service:

```
import [regular Ionic 2 and Angular 2 import stuffs];

declare var firebase: any;
@Injectable()
export class PushNotifService {

  constructor(private platform:Platform){
    console.log("PushNotifService starts");
    console.info(this.platform);
   console.info(firebase);
  }


}
```

It does not work, it seems that the `<script src="assets/js/firebase.js"></script>` [my project]/src/index.html  is not taken into account (it is not there when looking at the DOM with the Chrome console).

Any idea how to import the "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase.js" file without usin "npm install"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOME UPDATES:**

In the ionic 2 project there is [my project]/**src**/index.html and [my project]/**www**/index.html. I was editing [my project]/**src**/index.html and changes after "bundles update" while "ionic serve" runs in command prompt did not apply on [my project]/**www**/index.html.

Now I've updated [my project]/**www**/index.html with:

```
<body> 
  <ion-app></ion-app> 
  <script src="assets/js/firebase.js"></script> 
 //or   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase.js"></script>)

</body>
```

And it does work with service:

```
   import [regular Ionic 2 and Angular 2 import stuffs];

    declare var firebase: any;
    @Injectable()
    export class PushNotifService {

      constructor(private platform:Platform){
        console.log("PushNotifService starts");
        console.info(this.platform);
       console.info(firebase);
      }


    }
```

Afterwards I had to apply what is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673265/firebase-service-worker-not-found-while-using-gwt-404-error):

I created a "firebase-messaging-sw.js" empty file in "[my project]/www/".

And finally, as it is explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive), "[my project]/www/firebase-messaging-sw.js" must contain:

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': 'YOUR SENDER ID'
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

**NB**: I've detailed the steps that had caused me troubles thru the implementation, beside that getToken() or onMessage() from 
[firebase.messaging.Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging) managed to work in my `PushNotifService` class once those other things around were in place. I didn't detail the server side (PHP script to send messages or Firebase project settings).

Answer (score 0):

Angular ~12 has an angular.json file that in the middle contains a "scripts":[] array.  Firebase Messaging 9 seems to load the "firebase-messaging-sw.js" without allowing you to specify the path.

This works for me but you will need to rebuild your project to output the files.

```
"scripts": ["src/firebase-messaging-sw.js"]
```